# Why can't all Level Ds drink blood from blood capsules?

Tags: vampire-knight

In Vampire Knight, some Level Ds, vampires who were turned by other vampires, are unable to metabolize blood created from blood tablets (synthetic blood created by the Night Class). That is said clearly in the story, but is it ever explained?

Answer (score 1):

It could very well be genetic. In the manga, it's shown that Zero has been using Blood Tablets since Rido's destruction, there are 2 things which occurred around the time of Rido's destruction:

1. He drank Ichiru's blood, thus becoming the "complete" hunter he was supposed to be.
2. He drank Yuki's blood after she was turned back into a Pure-Blood.

We can rule out the second as Yuki's Blood at that time is Kuran blood, which Zero has had before from Kaname. Also, Yuki's blood as a human must have had some link to Kuran Blood as Rido also wanted it to be resurrected. So all that's left is the fact Zero had a genetic flaw since he was only a half-hunter.

In the anime, it only seems to reference that there are others like Zero, but Zero is the only one that I have seen, and I also have yet to seen anyone else in the manga either.

Comment: Please check whether my edit changes the meaning of your post. Thanks.

Comment: @nhahtdh the last sentence of the first paragraph (before the list) was talking about 2 thing which did happen, how you worded it made it sound like assumptions...tough i could have worded it better so i fixed up up slightly, the rest of your chnages is fine